# Queries slow down website and must make them execute faster

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, performance

I have 2 queries in wordpress that slow significantly my website. the first one is

```
   global $wpdb;
    $tbl = $wpdb->prefix . "my_tournament_matches_events";  
    $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM $tbl WHERE match_id = '$match' AND player_id = '$player' AND event_id = 'app'");
    if($result) { return 'checked="checked"';
```

The problem is that it checks for every single player (0.33sec) if he attended the game, which means 20 queries for each team (6.6sec and for both teams=13,2sec). I wonder if i could make it with only two queries (One for each team).

The second query is

```
    $output.="<td colspan='2'>".my_fetch_data_from_id($homeplayer->player_id,'data_value')."</td>";
    foreach($events as $event){
        $evcount = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(*) as total_events 
                                       FROM $table2 
                                       WHERE match_id='$mid' 
                                       AND player_id='$homeplayer->player_id' 
                                       AND event_id='$event->id'" );
        $total= $evcount[0]->total_events;

        $output.="<td><input type='text' name=hm-$homeplayer->player_id-$event->id value='$total'/></td>";
     }
```

In the second query it checks for each player, but since i have available about 11 events, that means, it executes 11events*20players*2teams=440 queries. Is it possible to alter the code to reduse number of queries and time of them? Average time of each of the second query is about 0,3sec, so every improvement will be noticable

Comment: For the first query you could set the limit to 1 meaning that if a result is found it will stop right away

Comment: Hi, you should first escape your variables inside the SQL query (e.g. `$match`).

Comment: avoid using `*`, use column names instead.

Comment: what is the full scenario here? Does the player login to a game? How do you identify a player is "in a game"?

Comment: A player is in game if i first, choose him to attend. Then the query add to the base an event called app, while the other columns will be players id, match id

Comment: Ok so could you not ID them via PHP, then update via JS, and just update the DB every 10 seconds?

Comment: make sure that columns used in where clause are properly indexed, at least plain indexed that would improve search, also if possible switch table engine to `MyISAM`.

Comment: @SuperDJ how can i limit to 1? do you have an example please?

Comment: @GiwrgosRad Example: `LIMIT 1`

Comment: If you could show a picture of the table structures we might be able to give you a more suiting answer

Comment: https://ibb.co/goGGMc the screenshot with matches events (including app and other events)

Comment: @GiwrgosRad with structure I mean somthing different than the content. It's actually a button in PHPmyadmin. Also you can just add the screenshot in the question

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://image.ibb.co/i5itZx/Screenshot_6.png).

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up:

- Add `LIMIT 1` to the queries this will make sure that if the query finds a result it doesn't continue looking for others;
- Avoid using `*` in `count` but only count on the required fields;
- Add indexes to columns where possible;

For readability, consistency and some errors you can change the single and double quotes:

```
$output.='<td colspan="2">'.my_fetch_data_from_id( $homeplayer->player_id, 'data_value' ).'</td>';
$output.='<td><input type="text" name="hm-'.$homeplayer->player_id-$event->id.'"value="'.$total.'"/></td>';
              // Seems odd here otherwise ^
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest adding two indexes in the database. (and ofc. checking if they are present)

```
ALTER TABLE my_tournament_matches_events 
    ADD INDEX index1 (`player_id`, `match_id`, `event_id`);

ALTER TABLE total_events 
    ADD INDEX index2 (`player_id`, `match_id`, `event_id`);
```

This should speed things up, considerably. 0.33s is a slow query response time.

Comment: How do you know what indexes do they have currently?

Comment: If the query performs that long, it's most probable that at least one of the tables is not indexed

Comment: Sure it's "possible" but it's still a guess, just ask in comment first then answer. You are providing `alter table` commands on a table you have no knowledge of at all

Comment: That's why I suggested first to check if the indexes are present.

Comment: We have no indexes, because the data from the tables, are often moved to another database, which is not possible to function the same

Comment: Without indexes the more data you have the slower it will get. Moving the data does not affect indexes of the particular table.

Comment: "*That's why I suggested first to check if the indexes are present.*" which is a comment, and why you have 3 dvotes - it's called an "answer" not "suggestion" ;) "*0.33 is a slow query response time*" also makes presumptions about the rest of their APP and database structure. Perhaps overall there are a billion queries per second to this DB...?

Comment: But what if the other table in the other database is not indexed? We also update matches about 20 times per day. wouldn' t that cause troubling in updating continously the index?

Comment: The database maintains indexes for all the operations. When you insert / change the data, database updates the index accordingly. This should not cause problems to moving the data, because the index is maintained with the structure (table definition), not with the data itself, e.g. when you move data you most probably will not move the index. The performance may be worse on updates / insert with indexes, but unless you have super high database loads - this will be hardly noticeable.

Comment: @GiwrgosRad, please post the result of your investigation, I'm personally interested in if it helped.

Comment: after tested with index it takes more time, due to many updates insertions done to the base. Unfortunately i did not conclude to a solution